# Sql Bulk Copy Cannot access destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, bulkinsert

I'm trying to read data from files and to use bulk copy to insert it in the database table.

When I try to run my code, I get the error: *"Cannot Access Denstination Table"*

Declaration of FlatTable.

```
System.Data.DataTable flatTableTempData = new System.Data.DataTable("FlatTable");

DataColumn DistrictColumn = new DataColumn();
DistrictColumn.ColumnName = "DistrictName";
// Create Column 3: TotalSales
DataColumn TownColumn = new DataColumn();
TownColumn.ColumnName = "TownName";
DataColumn FarmerColumn = new DataColumn();
FarmerColumn.ColumnName = "FarmerName";

flatTableTempData.Columns.Add(DistrictColumn);
flatTableTempData.Columns.Add(TownColumn);
flatTableTempData.Columns.Add(FarmerColumn);
```

This is my code, with the connection string and the insertion using bulk copy:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DRTARIQ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestDB2"))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
    {

        s.DestinationTableName = flatTableTempData.TableName;

        foreach (var column in flatTableTempData.Columns)
            s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

        s.BulkCopyTimeout = 500;
        s.WriteToServer(flatTableTempData);


    }
}
```

Comment: Does the user executing this code have sufficent permissions on the table? I believe at least SELECT and INSERT are required.

Comment: i read about the permissions how do we give the user such permissions...right now i need he insert permission

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `flatTableTempData`?

Comment: Just checking, but does the table "FlatTable" exist in the `TestDB2` database?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem. The table exists, the SQL user has access but SqlBulkCopy cannot access the table. My problem turned out to be I turned off the indexing to try and insert faster (rebuild index after the bulkcopy), but this made the table inaccessible. After I turned the indexing on again it worked, SqlBulkCopy has access to the table.

Comment: how did you turn on and off indexing?

Comment: "ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [Schema].[TableName] DISABLE" and to enable the index: "ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [Schema].[TableName] REBUILD", using ExecuteStoreCommand of ObjectContext.

Answer (score 1):

The table name in **WriteToServer** method of **SqlBulkCopy** must be surrounded with **[ ]** signs.

Comment: In my case, the `[]` signs are only required if the table name is a reserved word (e.g. `Group`). Thanks!